# Singlet or triplet carbene

Tags: organic-chemistry

On reaction of diazomethane with ethene a carbene is formed as a intermediate . This carbene then attacks on the double bond and form cyclopropane . However I read that both singlet and triplet carbene can react in this reaction but according to me since the carbon of carbene is overlapping with two different orbitals hence each electron of carbene must be in different orbital hence must be triplet. I can't find a reference to this on the internet, perhaps you all could help me .
[image]

Comment: part of the answer may be given here https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/50277/how-does-spin-flipping-of-triplet-carbenes-occur/54259#54259

Comment: I think a triplet carbene reacts in a stepwise fashion rather than a pericyclic concerted cyloaddition as in the singlet case. The triplet adds to one side then a spin flip must occur before radical combination. This leaves the possibility for stereochemical change

Comment: [This earlier answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/24125/making-three-membered-ring-using-different-reactants/24130#24130) may be helpful.

Comment: Ron I understood that part and thanks for help but my question is still unanswered that how come if carbon of carbene  has to overlap with two different orbitals of two carbon atoms

Comment: Then how can singlet carbene be possible .( Please see the previous three comments including this one as one )

Comment: @user3650050  Look at the diagram in my earlier answer.  Even in the singlet process the 2 bonds are formed sequentially, not at the same time.  It's just that the second bond forms much more rapidly with the singlet than the triplet so that stereochemistry is preserved with the singlet.

Answer (score 1):

Diazomethylene is singlet therefore carbene is formed in the singlet state.
singlet carbene is highly reactive therefore it goes through reaction probably before intersystem crossing (depends on competitive speeds). this is why singlet state of carbene is usually invisible. Triplet carbenes react like radicals unlike singlet state (besides some aryl carbenes) therefore the products are different. you can look up Skell-Woodworth for reaction of different spin states of carbenes.
based on the products you can find which spin state of the carbene has been involved in the reaction.